# How to read and write data from a RFID using serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, rfid

I'm trying to read/write data from a RFID using the serial port in C#.
I've used the code below but it doesn't work.
I've wrote a command from the manual, but the data received is totally different:

[Manual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qfGd.jpg)

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TagDetector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            mySerialPort.Open();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.Write("'CSE      '<LF><CR>");
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += mySerialPort_DataReceived;
        }

        void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write("Data Received:");
            Console.WriteLine(indata);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            mySerialPort.Close();
            mySerialPort.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing the `<LF><CR>` with `Enviroment.NewLine`, `\x0d\x0a`, `\r\n` and still doesn't works.

My application receives `Data Received:7?8?V7?7?7?7?7?7?7?` like a reply.
Between each character is a non-printing character:

I hope you can help me.
Thanks and sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: Try changing Parity Bits, Data Bits and Stop Bits in code and in the driver of the RFID. There is a huge chance that the device is not set correctly.

Comment: `"'CSE      '<LF><CR>"`  According to the documentation picture you linked, there are only 5 characters between CSE and the `'`, but you use 6 spaces. Secondly <LF><CR> stands for <line feed> (\n) and <carriage return> (\r), i.e. `\n\r` (not `\r\n`!!!). Hope that helps a little ;)

Comment: I saw the configuration and changed the protocol from `CR-16` to `<LF><CR>` and now I get:

`Data Received:7

7

7


`

There is two line feeds between each 7.

The stop bits and data bits cant be changed.
I changed the parity to Odd, None and Even, and got the same result.


elgonzo: You're right, but I get the same reply with `\n\r` and the 5 spaces.

Thanks for your coments!